# Cant install/setup scrivener in phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So I have Phoenix Project v1.3 and I want to add a pagination query in the backend. I'm trying to use [scrivener](https://hexdocs.pm/scrivener_ecto/readme.html#installation) to paginate my queries. But I'm stuck in the Installation Process.

**I'm getting a dependency error**

**mix.exs**

```
defp deps do
[
  {:phoenix, "~> 1.3.2"},
  {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
  {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.2"},
  {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
  {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
  {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
  {:cors_plug, "~> 1.5"},
  {:distillery, "~> 2.0"},
  {:comeonin, "~> 4.0"},
  {:bcrypt_elixir, "~> 1.0"},
  {:guardian, "~> 1.0"},
  {:scrivener_ecto, "~> 2.0"} # getting an error whenever I add this dependency
]end
```

and when running `mix deps.get`. I get an error of

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clearly stated in the error message, the latest `{:scrivener_ecto, "~> 2.0"}` depends on just-released *Ecto 3.0*, while *Phoenix 1.3* depends on *Ecto 2.1*.

According to semantic versioning the major version update is not considered compatible with the requirement.

You should go with `{:scrivener_ecto, "~> 1.3"}` *or* upgrade both *Phoenix* to `1.4` and *Ecto* to `3.0`.

Comment: Thanks for answering Im using 1.3 as you suggested its not throwing an error in `mix deps.get`. Im trying to make it work now thanks